# UIViewController subclass init not called when loading from nib

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, uikit, interface-builder, nib

I tried overriding the default initWithNibName designated initializer of a UIViewController subclass like so:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have also included its definition in the header file. However, when my Application Delegate nib loads the viewcontroller, the initializer is not invoked, only -viewDidLoad.

How does the nib magic instantiate my view controller then? Why do all the XCode templates state

> // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.

Is it correct my initWithNibName isn't called when the viewcontroller is loaded form another nib?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to put your initialization code inside the `awakeFromNib` method for it to be run when loaded from Nib. The Nib file contains an archived version of the objects that it contains, so in principle, they do not need to be initialized again.

Comment: Also, `-initWithCoder:` is the init method that's called when something instantiates from a nib.

Comment: (Reading the question again, though, `-awakeFromNib` is what's wanted here.)

Comment: Why -awakeFromNib rather than -viewDidLoad ?

Comment: some nibs do not have a viewDidLoad method, such as a UIView